# Structure of surface

Tags: differential-geometry

We define surface patches $\sigma^x_{\pm} : U \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}^3$ for $S^2$ by solving the equation $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ for $x$ in terms of $y$ and $z$:
$$\sigma^x_{\pm} (u, v)=(\pm \sqrt{1 - u^2 - v^2}, u, v),$$
defined on the open set $U = \{(u, v) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid  u^2 + v^2 < 1\}$. Define $\sigma^y_{\pm}$ and $\sigma^z_{\pm}$ similarly (with the same $U$) by solving for $y$ and $z$, respectively.

Show that these six patches give $S^2$ the structure of surface.

We have that $$\sigma^y_{\pm} (u, v)=(u,\pm \sqrt{1 - u^2 - v^2}, v) \\ \sigma^z_{\pm} (u, v)=(u,v,\pm \sqrt{1 - u^2 - v^2})$$

Could you give me a hint how we could show that these six patches give $S^2$ the structure of  surface?

Comment: For each pair of patches you need to show that the change of coordinates from one to the other is a diffeomorphism, i.e. smooth and jacobian is never zero

Comment: What do you mean by "the change of coordinates from one to the other" ? @user26977

Comment: Take two patches (as an example I use $\sigma^z_+$ and $\sigma_^y_+$). Any point on the sphere that has $y>0$ and $z>0$ has coordinates in both patches. Change of coordinates is a function that use coordinates in one patch as input and outputs the coordinates of the same point in the second patch. As an example change of coordinates from $\sigma^z_+$ to $\sigma^y_+$ would be $f(u,v) = (u,\sqrt{1-u^2-v^2})$.

Comment: Why is this the change of coordinates from $\sigma^z_+$ to $\sigma^y_+$ ? I haven't understood it... @user26977

Comment: Fix a point $A(\frac 12, \frac 12,\frac{\sqrt 2}2)$. We have $A=\sigma^z_+(\frac 12 , \frac 12)$. Try to find $u,v$  such that $A = \sigma^y_+(u,v)$. Can you do the same thing for the arbitrary point on a sphere such that $y>0$ and $z>0$

Comment: To find $u,v$ such that $A=\sigma^y_+(u,v)$, we have $$(\frac 12, \frac 12,\frac{\sqrt 2}2)=(u, \sqrt{1 - u^2 - v^2}, v) \\ \Rightarrow u=\frac{1}{2}, \sqrt{1 - u^2 - v^2}=\frac{1}{2}, v=\frac{\sqrt 2}2$$ For an arbitrary point on a shere $A=(x,y,z)$ we have that $A=\sigma^y_+(x,z)$, $A=\sigma^z_+(x,y)$ and $A=\sigma^x_+(y,z)$, right? @user26977

Comment: yes,  exactly. Then $f(x,y) = (x,z)$ and from the equation of the sphere you get $f(x,y) = (x,\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2})$.

Comment: So, do we have to show that this $f$ is smooth and the jacobian is never zero to get the desired result? @user26977

Comment: yes, that would be it for $\sigma^z_+$ and $\sigma^y_+$. Then repeat the same process for other pairs of $\sigma$s

Comment: Having found such an $f$ for all pairs of $\sigma$, how do we get then the desired result? How do we conclude that these six patches give $S^2$ the structure of surface? @user26977

Comment: Having such $f$  for each pair of $\sigma$'s means that 6 $\sigma$ patches form a structure of a surface on a sphere

Comment: Why does it mean that 6 $\sigma$ patches form a structure of a surface on a sphere? @user26977

Comment: Remember the definition of a surface structure

Comment: The definition of a surface is the following: $$$$ A subset $S$ of $R^3$ is a surface if, for every point $p \in S$, there is an open set $U$ in $R^2$ and an open set $W$ in $R^3$ containing $p$ such that $S \cap W$ is homeomorphic to $U$. $$$$ Do we consider that each of the $6$ patches is $S \cap W$ ? @user26977

Comment: yes exactly. The properties involving $f$ proves that the structure in hand is differentiable